# mediawiki cleanup extension?

Tags: wiki, mediawiki, extension

Are there any extensions to mediawiki that will allow for a button to mark a page as "needs cleanup" or "deprecated"?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no such extension. Wikipedia and other MediaWiki sites are using [templates](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates) for that purpose. See [Wikipedia's template messages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Template_messages) for a good example.

Comment: Yes, I spent the time adding in the ambox css stuff from the commons css. However, I could not get the templates to cleanly export from wikipedia to our wiki - so I created our own. An extension to tag a page or section with some markup would do the trick I think.

Answer (score 1):

Extension:RecentChangesCleanup